# Immigrant Visa Interview

Tags: usa

If you answered no to the DS 160 question "Do you have any relative in the US?" and later in life, a relative in the US files an immigrant petition on your behalf, will the consular officer easily notice the discrepancy during an immigrant visa interview?

Comment: Are we to infer that the relative was already in the US at the time of the DS160 application?

Comment: Knowingly telling a lie on a visa application can get you banned for life. You might be able to say you didn’t know you had a third cousin second removed, but it might be hard to say you didn’t know your brother was in the USA.

Comment: So you say "no" to the question while your relative is actually in the US; and, at some later date, a US citizen or resident relative files a petition for you. Please keep in mind that people who can be petitioned for are: spouse, children, parents and siblings. It's hard to imagine that you don't know if you have any of them are in the US at the time of your application.

Comment: The way you phrase your question and your comments make it look like you're planning to lie on your form. We cannot advise you to do that.

Comment: In fact, it is strongly advised *not* to lie on any immigration forms. The consequences can be dire. Basically, they are looking for a reason not to grant you a visa - if they find even the possibility of a reason, they will run with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, cheating or being deceptive is an automatic rejection in almost all cases. If by later in life you mean "1 year ago" and the relative was a close relative, like a brother or sister - that's hard to justify why you "forgot" to mention them.

If your application was 10 years ago and the relative is some distant cousin (or you are now related legally for example you have a brother in law due to a sibling marriage), then this is not deception.

The form asks about your *current status* (not in the future or the past) and the declaration you sign confirms that you are giving answers truthfully as to the best of your knowledge at the time of submission.

Immigration interviews are generally quite comprehensive - chances are they are well aware of your previous travel history to/from the US - and as you have to provide passports they may also be aware of your other non-US travel history.

Only the immigration officer knows if they have access to the forms you fill when applying for visas and how back of an archive they keep, or even if such forms are reviewed during an immigration interview, so no one can answer definitively.